# RabbitMQ Header Exchange based Shovel

Tags: rabbitmq, rabbitmq-exchange, rabbitmq-shovel, rabbitmq-federation

[image]

Hello Team,

Whats the bets way to solve this problem?

Solution 1 is to have mirror queues in vHost 1 for all corresponding destination queues and create a shovel between queues.
Is there any alternatives which avoids creating a mirror queue in source vhost?